# can you send ethereum to the same address you sent from?

Tags: ether

I was doing some financial investigation and I found transactions which had same account for source and target. Is this possible?

Comment: YES. That is possible

Comment: But why is it allowed?

Comment: The real question is why are you asking if it is possible when you've already found out that it is possible?

Comment: @user57191 Why should it not be allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's possible.

You can use it to store a transaction with a message attached on your address.